# R replace value in a column by a dictionary table without using merge or join

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dict table like:

```
id value
1 168833
2 367656
3 539218
4 892211
......(millions of lines)
```

and a original data frame like:

```
name code 
Abo   1
Cm3   2
LL2   6
JJ    15
```

how to replace the code column in the original table with dictionary table without using join or merge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `match` from `base R`

```
df1$value[match(df2$code, df1$id)]
```

---

Or another option is `hashmap`

```
library(hashmap)
hp <- hashmap(df1$id, df1$value)
hp[[df2$code]]
```

---

Based on the example in `?hashmap`, it works faster

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
     "R" = y[match(z, x)],
     "H" = H[[z]],
     times = 500L
 )
#Unit: microseconds
# expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    R 154.197 202.1625 240.5838 229.1625 245.1735 6853.756   500
#    H  15.861  19.0235  22.7721  22.4490  24.9670   62.230   500
```

Comment: OK, you get the value index like look up a dictionary by using match method match every code from the dict, and you using that index to get the correct value for each  code,good strategy! I hope there is some other solution if there is.

Comment: @cloudscomputes  can you update your post with all the functions that you don't need and the ones you wish in the expected output.  I only find `join` or `merge` so thought that `match` would be fine.  Have you checked `hashmap` or `hash`?

Comment: I think match is fine, I just don't want solutions with join or merge

Comment: But I am glad to see any other answer that can also solve this problem

Comment: @cloudscomputes  No problem.  I updated with a `hashmap` approch

Comment: Hi, hashmap package seems not in r cran anymore, Any recommendation package has similar function? @akrun